# Correct way to load values/properties from spring cloud consul

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud, consul

I have a spring boot application that has a lot of properties defined in a `.yml` file. I am moving away from having the properties in a file to having them in a cloud, so for this I am using the key/value feature in spring cloud consul.

I am able to retrieve a value for a given key from consul, but the only way I have seen documented and only way I have been able to do it is like so:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    String home() {
         return env.getProperty("test.property");
    }
```

This is fine and dandy, but I have some existing classes that are still set to load properties the old way:

```
@Value("${test.property}")
String testProperty;
```

After adding the dependency for spring cloud consul to my project, I get new errors saying that all these properties cannot be resolved. I assume it is because spring boot sees the consul dependency and is either ignoring the yml file or parts of it now.

Is there a way to get these properties to load from consul without having to change any code in the classes? Or will I need to change these classes to follow the example that uses the `env` object?

Also, any further insight into how spring cloud consul works with spring boot for this specific purpose would be greatly appreciated. There isn't a whole lot of documentation on it.

Comment: If you are using it with the Spring Cloud Config Client the `@Value` should simply work.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not, I am using Spring Cloud Consul

Comment: That is the server side, spring cloud consul can integrate quite easily with spring cloud config and then you get out-of-the-box what you want. See http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/spring-cloud-consul.html (the last section).

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have any documentation on that? Everything I have read so far has lead me to believe that if I want to connect to a consul agent through Spring, then I have to use spring cloud consul in my application. You are saying I can use spring cloud config in my application and point it to the server running consul?

Comment: Well not exactly spring-cloud-config but the consul counterpart (which is at the documentation in my previous comment).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using this consul counter-part. You posted documentation for spring cloud consul which I mentioned I am already using. Using spring cloud consul does not auto-resolve the `@Value` tags. If it is supposed to, then I can't find the documentation on how to get it to work that way and thus is the reason I made this post.

Comment: Can you post your application yml and the code to get property. I have difficulty in reading the key value from consul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work, but it was a little tricky. You need to have the spring cloud consul starter dependency added. I had just the spring cloud consul config dependency.

I had to add consul config properties to both my application.yml and bootstrap.yml, the properties in my boostrap just set the format and data-key:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      config:
        format: YAML
        data-key: data
```

This tells spring boot to load a yaml blob that is the value of key data in my application config cloud directory.

The configuration in my application.yml is the default they provide in the example. Once I added those configs and the @autoconfiguration tag to my service main application class, everything started working.